# Сайт на ReactJS с админкой (общий вопрос)

Tags: reactjs

Хочу написать простенький сайт-блог на ReactJS, чтобы изучить его.

Сразу встает вопрос – а как будет выглядеть админка и на чем ее писать?)

Все предыдущие проекты были на WordPress, но здесь, как я понимаю, другая история и нет каких-то CMS (конечно могу ошибаться). Подскажите, куда копать и какие статьи читать, что гуглить? Сразу хотелось бы выстроить нормальную архитектуру.

Comment: Админка будет выглядеть так как вы ее напишите. Админка это по сути тот же самый _сайт-блог_ только со своими функциями. Самая простая архитектура `clinet -> server <- client-admin` где `client` это фактический сайт, который вы сами пишите. _другая история_ - это очень мягко сказано. Использовать СMS и потом начать использовать JS либу. Это как идти в одну сторону и потом развернуться на 355 градусов и пойти обратно.

Comment: @Александр доступно, спасибо) Если не сложно, можно ссылочку, что почитать на эту тему? А так в любом случае напишите ответ, я отмечу!

Comment: Вам стоит изучить по отдельности несколько технологий. Как вариант вы можете взять за основу https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/458096/. Но у вас довольно субъективный вопрос и правильного ответа на этот вопрос может не быть. Так как как именно построить архитектуру зависит только от вашего желания.